# How to add clipboard module to QuillField() in django for using in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, quill

Copying and pasting are not handling correctly on the Quill Editor. Is there any additional instructions which are needed when using the QuillField() in django to properly enable it, specially for copying text documents with images?

This is how I am doing it:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='post_customer')   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='posts_author')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    asset = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_ASSET, default=0)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_STATUS, default=0)
    article = QuillField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I found no way out of this, I have switched the editor to CKEditor.